# Unique constraint for NULL value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate CSV data to MySQL using PHP.

I have a CSV file of Fuel Dispense record for a pertol pump. The CSV files has the following fields (DateTime, Vehicle_Reg, Quantity, Odometer... ...). I have created a table in MySQL database which contains the following fields -

**vehicle_fuel_dispense (id, dispense_time, vehicle, mileage, quantity, uploaded_by)**. Id is auto increment PK and (dispense_time, vehicle) is UNIQUE to prevent duplicate entries.

**In the CSV file Vehicle_Reg field could be NULL.**

The problem is, when I reupload the same datafile, it creates a duplicate entry in MySQL for the rows where Vehicle_Reg is null.

I could make (dispense_time, vehicle) a composite PK and get rid of ID from the table which could solve the problem. But I need the ID field in the MySQL database a PK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lets start by showing us the actual schema for this table please. If you are not sure how to do the Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: @Akina I have updated the question and attached few screenshots.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have atached a screenshot of the schema

Comment: Screenshots are not useful. Paste as formatted textual code/data.

Comment: As I see the CSV column named `Vehicle_Reg` is saved into the table to the column `vehicle`. So your UNIQUE index cannot detect duplicates. Does some another expression which allows that the row to be inserted exists in the table already? If not then the task is not solvable, noway to understand that the row is already present in the table.

Comment: Alternatively I can offer you to save the parameters of loaded CSV into some service table (of course the importing process must be performed by stored procedure in this case).

Comment: "As I see the CSV column named Vehicle_Reg is saved into the table to the column vehicle. So your UNIQUE index cannot detect duplicates" - I do not understand how this is related here. I am using a PHP script to MAP the fields. The vehicle field in MYSQL table is a foreign key refereing to Vehicle(id). Please read Vatev comment below - "NULL values are not equal to each other by design. The UNIQUE constraint also follows that logic" - and this is the problem here that I am trying to sort out

Answer (score 1):

NULL values are not equal to each other by design. The UNIQUE constraint also follows that logic, and allows multiple NULLs. There are a few options to resolve this:

- Insert empty values ('',0, 0000-00-00,... etc) instead of NULLs.
- Make the columns NOT NULL. This will have mostly the same effect as the composite PK.
- Change the table to the composite PK, and add an auto-increment column which is not a PK.

Comment: Thank you for this. The vehicle field in MYSQL table is a foreign key refereing to Vehicle(id) , So I think, first 2 solutions will not work in this case. and I do not want to remove ID as primary key.